# Implementing Multi threading with Polymorphic Classes

Tags: c++

I am trying to implement a Logic system for my game which takes `dt` as its parameter
So far I have done this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <memory>

class Player {
private:
    float x, y;
public:
     Player(float initX, float initY)
         : x(initX), y(initY) {}

     void Logic(float dt) {
         //Do some Logic
     }
}

bool isLogicThreadActive = true;
class GameState {
    public:
    virtual void Logic(float) = 0;
}

class PlayState : public GameState {
    private:
       Player player;
    public:
       PlayState() {
           player = Player(0.0f, 0.0f); 
       }

    void Logic(float dt) override {
        while(isLogicThreadActive) {
            player.Logic(dt);
        }
    }
}

class Game {
private:
    std::unique_ptr<GameState> gameState;
    float dt;
public:
    Game() {
        gameState = std::make_unique<PlayState>();
        dt = 0.0f;
    }

    void Logic() {

       std::thread logicThread([&]() { gameState->Logic(dt); });

       auto t1 = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
       while(isLogicThreadActive) {
           auto t2 = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
           dt = (float)std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(t2 - t1).count();
           t1 = t2;
       }

       if (logicThread.joinable()) {
           logicThread.join();
       }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the value of dt is not being updated in the Logic Thread.
Due to this the player is not moving when provided with Input from Main Thread.

**However when I tried using std::cout in PlayState::Logic(float dt) method, it started to work.
Can you explain this and also a solution to how to update the dt variable in thread without affecting FPS?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is that the value of dt is not being updated in the Logic Thread.

That's ambiguous - are you expecting it to be updated by the Logic thread? 
 If so - it can't be: `void Logic(float dt)` takes `dt` by value - it can't update `dt`.  Note that the by-reference capture in the lambda just means the `Logic` function copies from `main`'s `dt` when called, not a further copy inside the lambda.

If you mean updates in the main thread can't be observed in the logic thread: there's a race condition - `dt = (float)std::chrono::duration_cast...` may be called before or after `gameState->Logic(dt);` copies it.

All that said, you're trying to update `dt` across threads when it's not atomic, and you're not using any synchronisation functions - it may or may not work.

You really need to read a couple threading introductions or you'll write unreliable code.

Comment: I wanted to update the dt variable inside of main thread and access the updated dt value inside of Logic(float dt) method

Comment: Then you need to make `dt` a type designed to automatically synchronise across threads - you could `#include <atomic>` and make `dt` a `std::atomic<float>`, but you'll need to your `Logic` functions to accept it by reference - `void Logic(const std::atomic<float>& dt)`.  Just be careful as it can change at any time, so simple things like `if (x < dt && y > dt)` no longer imply `x < y`.  Copy it to an actual `float` and use that multiple times if that better suits your logic.

Comment: `std::atomic<float>` creates a `float` that automatically synchronises across threads, and - in general - `std::atomic` also ensures that a reading thread will either see the value prior to another thread's update, or the value afterwards.  It might seem obvious that one or the other would be seen, but actually for certain types at certain memory alignment on certain hardware, it's possible for the memory to be updated in stages.  Also, say two threads do value += 1: you don't want them both to read the current value N, add one, then both write the same N+1 value; you want N+2: just use atomic